# Search & Replace Request URI Filter in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

I have 2 landing pages:

```
/aa/index.php/aa/index/[sessionID]/alpha
/bb/index.php/bb/index/[sessionID]/bravo
```

Because the sessionID is unique, each of the landing page will be tracked as different pages. Therefore, I need a filter to remove the sessionID. These are what i want to track:

```
/aa/index.php/aa/index/alpha
/bb/index.php/bb/index/bravo
```

I created the Search and Replace Custom Filter on the Request URI:

```
Search String: /(aa|bb)/index\.php/(aa|bb)/index/(.*)
Replace String: /$1/index.php/$2/index/$3
```

But i get the `/$1/index.php/$2/index/$3` being reported on the dashboard the next day. So i tried `/\1/index.php/\2/index/\3` but i got very strange results, `//aa/index.php/aa/index/alpha/index.php/aa/index/aa`.

Does anyone know how to reference the grouped patterns in the replace string?

**My Solution:**
i managed to solve it using Advanced Filter. My solution:

```
Field A => Request URI: /(aa|bb)/index\.php/(aa|bb)/index/(.*)/(.*) 
Field B => - 
Output to => Request URI: /$A1/index.php/$A2/index/$A4
```

Comment: I think you may have to use an [Advanced Filter](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034836&topic=1034830&ctx=topic) instead of a Search and Replace filter.

Comment: Thanks! i managed to solve it using Advanced Filter. Solution is in my post.

Comment: You should add that as an answer instead of an edit and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the Google Analytics regex engine, but it appears to me that `\1` is referencing the entire match (which in other regex implementations is called `\0`), while `\2` is the first group, `\3` is the second group, and so on.

Your initial regex, however, looks incomplete--I think it should look as follows:

```
Search String: /(aa|bb)/index\.php/(aa|bb)/index(/.*)/(alpha|bravo)
Replace String: /\2/index.php/\3/index/\5
```

(Note that I'm not sure whether `?` is supported in this regex implementation as the non-greedy modifier, but if it is, the above search string pattern might run a little faster if you change `/.*` to `/.*?`.)

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately, the sessionID is still appearing in the GA report under Standard Report > Content > Site Content > All Pages. As for the (alpha|bravo), i have more than 15 combinations, as such i have used /(aa|bb)/index\.php/(aa|bb)/index(/.*)/(.*) to group it instead.

Comment: That grouping looks fine to me--you're no longer missing that last `/`, which was the main problem.

As for the sessionID still appearing, are you saying that the search and replace filter now does nothing at all?

Comment: Yes, it seems the search and replace filter does nothing at all. Anyways, i have solved it with Advanced filter. My solution above...